# What is going on with the object?

Tags: python

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can explain me the following. I’m the newest in Python as well as in programming. May be it make no sense at all.

When I use this snippet it returns me None:

```
(in) dic = {'a':1, 'b':2}
(in) print(dic.update({'c':3})) 
(out) None
```

but when I use this one it returns me updated dic:

```
(in) dic = {'a':1, 'b':2}
(in) dic.update({'c':3})
(in) print(dic)
(out) {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Why is it? Why I have to conform to the order exactly?

further edited...
Ok. I do not understand yet. Is there any connections/relations with this code:

```
(in) lst = [1,3,2,4,6,5]
(in) print(lst.sort())
(in) print(sorted(lst))

(out) None
(out) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In both cases either function or method the list is supposedly sorted. But 
 when i call a print via method it returns None.

```
(in) lst = [1,3,2,4,6,5]
(in) lst.sort()
(out) print(lst)
```

Comment: Because `update` modifies your dict and returns `None`. That seems pretty clear from the code.

Comment: Tangentially related: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. `dic` and `dic.update(...)` are expressions which simply evaluate to two distinct objects.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are trying to print the return value of the `dic.update` call. There isn't one.

In the second case you are printing the modified dictionary itself.

The two programs basically do completely different things, and it has nothing to do with any "order".

Answer (score 1):

```
type(dic.update({'c':3})) 
>>> <class 'NoneType'>

type(dic)
>>> <class 'dict'>

type(sum)
>>> <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Try type(), you will find the difference. Some "function" updates the object while returning "None", e.g. object.append(), object.sort().

Answer (score 0):

Without reading the docs, I guess that the `update` method indeed updates the object (dic), but returns nothing (`None`). `print` prints what is returned by `update`, i. e. nothing. Try adding `print(dic)` right after the first `print`.